# Best way of creating layout in pyqt5 to be resposive?

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, pyqt5, responsive

So I am curren]tly working on an app for image processing. I am using PyQt5 for this purpose. You can see how it looks like now on the picture below. My question is, what is the best way to make it responsive, meaning, if I resize the window, all the widgets will rescale as well. Right now I am using some groupboxes, Hlayouts, VLayouts.

Only thing that comes to my mind is to create a gridlayout, though I would like to know, if there is by any chance any other possibility how to easily do it, since there is quite a lot of widgets.

Also, I would like to ask about GroubBox widget. Down left I have four buttons which are in one groupbox whose border is set to none by  self.tableButtonsGroupBox.setStyleSheet("tableButtonsGroupBox {border: none}"), but there is still visible the upper line. Is there way to get rid of it?

Thank you for suggestions in advance!
 [image]

Comment: maybe this line is not border of groupbox but border of some other empty element.

Comment: It only appeared once I created the groupbox @furas

Comment: what happen if you remove groupbox. ? Do yo stil see line ?

Comment: If I remove it, there is no line at all